# In html5, if you create a game etc., are you exposing all your source code?

Tags: javascript, html, obfuscation

In html5, if you create a game etc., are you exposing all your source code?

Comment: I can still remember the days when sharing code was considered a *good thing*.

Comment: What difference would it make?  Even if you weren't, someone could do the exact same thing you did fairly easily.  It's not as if you will do something with HTML5 that would be impossible to figure out.  Even if you were to do some crazy complex algorithm client-side, someone will still be able to get at it.  Even if you distributed binaries in a traditional sense, someone can disassemble it and figure it out.

Comment: @Brad the goal of obfuscation is not to make it impossible to copy, but instead to hopefully make it make it more difficult than it would be to recreate from scratch.  It is a deterence, not a stopping measure.

Comment: added obfuscation javascript tags to your question.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are exposing all your source code.

Answer (score 6):

Not specifically.  You are probably exposing all of your client code.  If the application makes calls to the server (such as AJAX requests) you can hide all of the game logic and source code for calculations done by the server.  So, for example, if you are planning on making a multi user game or a game that is controlled by a remote server, then you may or may not be exposing ALL of your source code.

Additionally, there are tools for obfuscating and shortening javascript which could help hide client logic from casual users.

Comment: There are a number of helpful tools for de-obfuscating JavaScript.  I wouldn't bother with that part of the step.  Casual users who don't know how to do this aren't your competition.